# Getting user e-mail with facebook C# sdk

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

Good evening!
I'm developing a web application with asp.net C#. In this application the user has the option to create  a login using its facebook account (facebook connect).

I'm using thye facebook  C# sdk from codeplex (http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/).
I can easily retrieve the name, photo , etc.... but I don't know how to retrieve the user e-mail.

To call the FB login button I use this code:

```
<fb:login-button onlogin="window.location.reload()" perms='email'></fb:login-button>
```

It works just fine and to retrieve user's info I use this C# code:

```
            // Authenticated, created session and API object
        sessaoFB = new ConnectSession(APPLICATION_KEY, SECRET_KEY);   

        if (!sessaoFB.IsConnected()) {
            this.phLogar.Visible = true;
            this.phLogado.Visible = false;
        } else {

            // Authenticated, create API instance
            _facebookAPI = new Api(sessaoFB);
            Auth auth = new Auth(sessaoFB);

            if (!this.Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                this.phLogar.Visible = false;
                this.phLogado.Visible = true;

                try
                {
                    //User data
                    user usuarioFB = _facebookAPI.Users.GetInfo();
                    this.lblNome.Text = usuarioFB.first_name;                        
                    imgFoto.ImageUrl = usuarioFB.pic_big;                        
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    this.lblNome.Text = ex.Message;
                }

            }
        }
```

How can I get the user's e-mail suing the facebook C# sdk? Do any of you guys know?

Thanks in advance for any help!
Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

André,

Your login-buttons is already requesting the permission to access the email address.

Why don't you use the FacebookClient? If you're running .NET 4.0, it's so simple as this:

```
var client = new FacebookClient();
dynamic me = client.Get("me");
string firstName = me.first_name;
string lastName = me.last_name;
string email = me.email;
```

Check this documentation: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20Examples&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Thanks Guilherme for your answer!

Comment: I used the sample above and the email is always null.

Comment: I am using client.get("me"), and response does not contain field email, can somebody help me please with this?

Comment: You need to get scope?Email as well. I'm working on this too now.

Comment: I'm about to explode at how common this type of answer is and I have to say something, because I'm obviously missing something.  How does `"/me"` get me a user's information.  Wouldn't that just be "MY" information?  How do I pass a User's ID?  I don't want me, I want them.

Comment: This question has almost 5 years old. You should create a new question, but the /me answered this question as he wanted to get the authenticated user (which is always /me if the token is properly issued).

Comment: For anyone else that runs into this, you need to be explicit in the call to `client.get("me")` and include the fields you want to access (having already requested permissions when logging in the specified user, of course): example: `client.Get("me?fields=gender,email,name");`
Full list of possible fields: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/